# Populate data validation via GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that populates data validations on one tab (Estimate) by populating rows in another tab (itemDataValidations) that I use as the range or helper.  What I'd like to do is skip this helper process and have the script populate the data validation directly; "List of items" instead of "List from range."

Unfortunately, I have limited knowledge of GAS and have had 0 success in my attempts thus far.

Here's the snippet of the script that handles the data validation...

```js
  // Populate item data validations

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){

    // if we're in the 'Items' tab, we don't need to populate 
    // the 'item' or 'sub item' fields.
    if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Items') return;

    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var item = itemDVss.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),activeCell.getColumn(),itemss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var itemIndex = item[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 2;

    if(itemIndex != 0){

      var itemValidationRange = itemDVss.getRange(activeCell.getRow(),3,1,itemDVss.getLastColumn());
      var itemValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(itemValidationRange).build();

      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(itemValidationRule);

    }
  }
```

[Here's the full script](https://script.google.com/d/1oz6GOXEA22_ghSyDqV-cp8BnEhsMGjBlJ5XcSQ4kB3lAh2OR6d-7JmAI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, in the case of the script in your question, how about modifying from ``var itemValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(itemValidationRange).build()`` to ``var itemValidationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(itemValidationRange.getValues()[0]).build()``? I obtained this modification from your shared Spreadsheet. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike!  That's definitely a step in the right direction.  At least the values are "permanent", which is my ultimate goal.  The problem I'm facing is when I delete a row in the tab that has the data validations (Estimate), the corresponding row in the "helper" (itemDataValidations) tab doesn't change, thus shifting all of my data validations rules.  If that makes any sense...
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, when ``requireValueInList`` is used for each conditional branch of "if" of the script of ``dynDD.gs``, the lists of data validations can be done the items independent on the range. In this case, when OnEdit event trigger is run, the columns "B" to "D" are changed from the range to items by the script of ``dynDD.gs``. But the existing all data validations are not changed. If you want to change the existing data from the range to the items, it is required to prepare the script. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: For example, if you use new Spreadsheet, I think that your can achieve the goal by modifying the script of ``dynDD.gs``.